# How to hide context menu from DataGrid header?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, contextmenu

I'm using a ContextMenu on the right click on a DataGrid. I don't want to show the ContextMenu on the DataGrid header.

```
<dgWPFCtrl:SelfBindingDataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="_cycleList"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentElementsList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           IsReadOnly="False"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentItem}">
    <dgWPFCtrl:SelfBindingDataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenCycleCommand}" Header="CYCLE" CommandParameter="CYCLE"/>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenCycleCommand}" Header="H1" CommandParameter="H1"/>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenCycleCommand}" Header="PDF" CommandParameter="PDF"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </dgWPFCtrl:SelfBindingDataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I removed tags in the question title. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change ContextMenu just for the header with `ColumnHeaderStyle`:

```
<dgWPFCtrl:SelfBindingDataGrid>
    <dgWPFCtrl:SelfBindingDataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </dgWPFCtrl:SelfBindingDataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```